# How to restrict a hibernate criteria to a specific root entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a dynamic query using hibernates criteria  language. I'm stunned as I'm unable to find any information regarding restricting the root entity dynamically (i.e. without specifying the id property).

I have an interface `IEntity`. There are several entities implementing `IEntity`. Some of them have an ID-property `id` while others have another ID-property (`shadowId`).

I want to write a single method covering both cases. Here is what I got so far:

```
@Override
public boolean querySomething(final IEntity ent) {
  final Criteria criteria =
    currentSession().createCriteria(HibernateUtils.deproxy(ent.getClass()));
  criteria.createAlias("sharedProperty", "prop");
  //This does not work:
  criteria.add(Property.forName("this").eq(ent)); 
  criteria.setProjection(Projections.count("prop.anotherProperty"));
  final Number result = (Number) criteria.uniqueResult();
  return result != null && result.longValue() > 0;
}
```

I would like to avoid to have a if statement like

```
if (ent instanceof TypeWithPropertyId){
  criteria.add(Property.forName("id").eq(ent));
} else {
  criteria.add(Property.forName("shadowId").eq(ent));
}
```

**Edit**

*Note: `HibernateUtils.deproxy(Class<?> clazz)` removes any Proxy and returns the original class.*

As of now, I didn't find anything in the criteria api which could help me. But I found `IdentifierEqExpression` by accident. Sadly `IdentifierEqExpression` still needs the ID Value and can not extract it itself. So for the moment I'm using a custom extension:

```
public class ThisEqualsExpression extends IdentifierEqExpression {

  public ThisEqualsExpression(final Object value, final SessionFactory sf) {
    super(sf.getClassMetadata(deproxy(value.getClass())).getIdentifier(value, null));
  }
}
```

I would prefer not using this hack-ish approach, but I still like this better than an `if`-statement:

```
public boolean querySomething(final IEntity ent) {
  final Criteria criteria =
    currentSession().createCriteria(HibernateUtils.deproxy(ent.getClass()));
  criteria.createAlias("sharedProperty", "prop");
  //This does work:
  criteria.add(new ThisEqualsExpression(ent, currentSession().getSessionFactory())); 
  criteria.setProjection(Projections.count("prop.anotherProperty"));
  final Number result = (Number) criteria.uniqueResult();
  return result != null && result.longValue() > 0;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
As requested some clarification:

In pure SQL, i *have* something like

```
SELECT COUNT(bar.property) 
FROM Foo foo
INNER JOIN Bar bar ON foo.bar_id=bar.id
```

But I *want* something like

```
SELECT COUNT(bar.property) 
FROM Foo foo
INNER JOIN Bar bar ON foo.bar_id=bar.id
WHERE foo.id=<some ID> --This is the important part
```

Back to Java:
`Foo`s ID-Property depends on its type. It may be `id` (which I used in the SQL example above), but it could also be some other property. I was wondering if there was a way to restrict a criterias root entity without knowing the propertys name.

Comment: why do you want to avoid such an IF statement? isn't that why you use `Criteria` in the first place?

Comment: It bloats up the code without adding anything meaningfull. And since hibernate does already know everything it needs, I would hate to implement this if statement if there was a way hibernate provides already.

Comment: i don't really understand what you want to achieve exactly, but did you read the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs and didn't find anything useful.

Comment: `currentSession().createCriteria(HibernateUtils.deproxy(ent.getClass()));` sets the root entity for the criteria. if you could explain it a bit better, what you try to achieve (what the query should do), i could help better. currently i have no clue what you want to do

Comment: i doubt that there is a smoother way than what you currently have